# Outlook recipients fields appear double

Tags: outlook, office365

Don't know if this is the right forum to ask, but here goes.

After installing Office 365, I am experiencing the following screen from Outlook when trying to send an email.

[image: Outlook error]

Have you seen this before and what can be done to change it?

Comment: I don't think it's right place to ask, I voted to move it as it should belong to [SU].

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have moved the question to the Super User page.